# Date range2 Field Validator not firing

Tags: forms, datetime

I am attempting to create a validator on a birthday (date) field I added to the user. The validator is setup as such but it never fires when I test it by registering a new user on the front-end.

[image: Field validation screen for the Date range2 validator.]

Anyone have any ideas why this validator isn't firing?

Comment: You are trying to register a user account as an anonymous user on `user/register` and not creating accounts from the admin screen, right?  The admin probably has bypass validation permission...

Comment: No I did it the normal user/register way in IE which has no session. I'm only logged in as admin in Chrome.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas why this validator isn't firing?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution that might help to simplify the challenge in your question, is the fairly new [Math Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/mathfield) module (for D7). Some more details about this module (from its project page):

> The Math Field module defines a new field type to dynamically calculate values on entity forms. **This is an alternative to [Computed Field](https://drupal.org/project/computed_field)
>   that does not require the use of PHP Filter.**
>
> Math expression fields are dynamically updated via ajax on the entity form as soon as all necessary fields are populated. If JavaScript is disabled, the field will be evaluated when the form is submitted. The result is stored in the database when the form is submitted.

By creating some auxiliary field(s) (calculated via the Math field), you may be able to complete your puzzle via some additional logic implemented via the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module, to actually verify "18 Years or Older" (which I believe is the actual validation you want to implement).

For more details (step-by-step instructions), refer to either of these links:

- the (amazing!) [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2484065) about the Math Field module.
- the interesting article about [Introducing the Math Field module](https://www.monarchdigital.com/blog/2015-06-22/introducing-math-field-module), which also includes some screenprints to see it at work (such as the the add/edit form example).