# Webform validate 18 years old (GNU Date Input Format)

Tags: 6, webforms, datetime, forms

I'm looking for a **valid** [webform](/questions/tagged/webform) date pattern, to validate a user's birthday (`component date`).

I want to make sure the person is 18 years of age or older. However, Drupal requires the [GNU Date Input Format](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_chapter/Date-input-formats.html).

[image: Screenshot of a webform backend (Drupal 6)]

**This seems not to work** - Drupal shows no error message at all ?

[image: Webform input - 24.09.2014]

There is also a related answer [Field Validation: 18 Years or Older](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/81433/field-validation-18-years-or-older), but this seems to be super complicated and does not affect the [webform](/questions/tagged/webform) module.

Comment: Why not to use `18 years ago`? Using date arithmetic might well be unsuppoted, as it's not really a date *format*, it's date *calculation*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's the solution for this annoying "feature":**

[image: Drupal validate 18 years old webform]

Comment: Please keep your language civil and avoid emotional attitude. Now you are pretty close to "inappropriate for respectful discourse" flag reason.